# String creation and comparison in Drag n' drop game

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to make a simple drag and drop game where users need to re order someone's name by dragging characters into a dropping zone.

I'm ok with the drag and drop animations but I'm not being able (mostly due to technical lack of skills) to create strings with this letters in order to make a comparison between both of them.

Check my example code here [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/estebanrao/pbrvE/)

I'm creating the first string with the name before I randomize all the letters `dragItemsContent = [];`

I'm kinda being able to create a new string for letters I'm dragging `dragedItemsContent += ui.draggable.text();`
But when I wan't to delete any of those letters I can't delete them, and the worst thing is I have no idea how to look for that letter's index and delete it properly from my string.

I'm using `data-letra` which is a unique indicator for each letter, maybe it can help.

So, to sum up, I need to add/remove letters (or some comparable data) to my strings and compare them to know if the users finish the game correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `dragedItemsContent += ui.draggable.text();` you should use `dragedItemsContent.push(ui.draggable.text())` this way you will get a good array in proper order. Later you can use `toString` to make your string and to remove simply remove the element from the array

You might also want to check out [sortable from jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/) which can handle almost everything out of the box

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've used push to populate my array and then splice to delete letters from it. You can check the working game here http://jsfiddle.net/estebanrao/pbrvE/

Answer (score 2):

Very fun game.

I have edited it to display `You Won!` or `Sorry. Please try again.` based on the results (Spelling out `Fredfigglehorn`.

[Clicky](http://jsfiddle.net/pbrvE/5/).

The important part is:

```
var letters = $('.drop-area').find('.drag-item');
if (letters.length == dragItemsLength ) {
    var final = '';
    for (var i=0;i<dragItemsLength;i++)
        final += letters[i].innerText.substring(0, 1);
    if (final == 'fredfigglehorn')
        alert("You won!");
    else
        alert("Sorry. Please try again.")
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dave, but my main problem was that letters may be deleted if you know you make a mistake, that's why I need to store everything in an array. I've fixed everything now and it's working. Check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/estebanrao/pbrvE/

Answer (score 0):

I have made a fiddle for u which does comparison based drag items text hope it helps u..       http://jsbin.com/oluhuk/2/edit